# Django File-based session doesn't expire

Tags: django, session

I just realized that my session doesn't expire when I use file-based session engine. Looking at Django code for file-based session, Django doesn't store any expiration information for a session, thus it's never expire unless the session file gets deleted manually.

This looks like a bug to me, as the database-backed session works fine, and I believe regardless of what session back-end developer chooses, they all should behave similarly.

Switching to database-backed session is not an option for me, as I need to store user's session in files.

Can anyone shed some lights?
Is this really a bug?
If yes, how do you suggest me to work around it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it looks like you're right. At least in django 1.4, using `django.contrib.sessions.backends.file` totally ignores `SESSION_COOKIE_AGE`.  I'm not sure whether that's really a bug, or just undocumented.

If you really need this functionality, you can create your own session engine based on the file backend in contrib, but extend it with expiry functionality.

Open `django/contrib/sessions/backends/file.py` and add the following imports:

```
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone
```

Then, add two lines to the `load` method, so that it appears as below:

```
def load(self):
    session_data = {}
    try:
        session_file = open(self._key_to_file(), "rb")
        if (timezone.now() - datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(self._key_to_file()))).total_seconds() > settings.SESSION_COOKIE_AGE:
            raise IOError
        try:
            file_data = session_file.read()
            # Don't fail if there is no data in the session file.
            ....
```

This will actually compare the last modified date on the session file to expire it.

Save this file in your project somewhere and use it as your `SESSION_ENGINE` instead of `'django.contrib.sessions.backends.file'`

You'll also need to enable `SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST` in your settings if you want the session to timeout based on inactivity.

Comment: Yea I'm thinking about this route too as the last resort.

Comment: I should probably ask at Django Users or Django developer mailing list, if this is indeed a bug

Comment: Why does `SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST` need to be enabled? Doesn't that defeat the purpose of expiring the session by setting a new modification time every time a request is made?

Comment: Without the `SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST`, the session will expire after `SESSION_COOKIE_AGE` seconds regardless of activity. If that's what you want, then don't bother with `SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST`. If you want it to only expire after `SESSION_COOKIE_AGE` seconds of inactivity, then you want `SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST` to be `True`

Comment: Oh ok got it. I do want to expire the session regardless of activity. Thanks for the quick response. Btw, can you update your answer to mention about this (the actual purpose of `SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST`)? It might be helpful for others.

Comment: You suggestion is excellent `you can create your own session engine based on the file backend in contrib, but extend it with expiry functionality`, but what you are actually doing is modifying the default session storage in your answer - which is not the right way to do it. Your fix is not upgrade friendly or portable.

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to use `tmpwatch` in the directory where you store the sessions

Comment: I like this idea as it's simple to implement. However, it requires the system to have `tmpwatch`.

Answer (score 0):

I hit similar issue on `Django 3.1`. In my case, my program calls the function `set_expiry(value)` with an integer argument (`int` data type) before checking session expiry.

Accoring to [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase.set_expiry), the data type of argument `value` to `set_expiry()` can be `int` , `datetime` or `timedelta`. However for file-based session, [expiry check inside `load()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/302caa40e4caab7d95ef7d0a88a90f935039ab09/django/contrib/sessions/backends/file.py#L92) doesn't work properly only if `int` argument is passed to `set_expiry()` beforehand, and such problem doesn't happen to `datetime` and `timedelta` argument of `set_expiry()`.

The simple solution (workaround?) is to avoid `int` argument to `set_expiry(value)`, you can do so by subclassing `django.contrib.sessions.backends.file.SessionStore` and overriding `set_expiry(value)` (code sample below), and change parameter `SESSION_ENGINE` accordingly in `settings.py`

```
from datetime import timedelta
from django.contrib.sessions.backends.file import SessionStore as FileSessionStore

class SessionStore(FileSessionStore):
    def set_expiry(self, value):
        """ force to convert to timedelta format """
        if value and isinstance(value, int):
            value = timedelta(seconds=value)
        super().set_expiry(value=value)
```

**Note**:
It's also OK to pass `timedelta` or `datetime` to `set_expiry(value)` , but you will need to [handle serialization issue on `datetime` object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54468299/9853105).